# Unable to start hive in terminal

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using `hive` for querying and data processing purpose in my hadoop main node,but I am not able to start `hive` in terminal and way taking too much time and not starting as show below.

```
#hive
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.3.4.7-4/0/hive-log4j.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

you can lookup for the actual problem in HIVE 
Hive uses log4j for logging. 
By default logs are not emitted to the console by the CLI. 
The default logging level is WARN for Hive releases prior to 0.13.0. Starting with Hive 0.13.0, the default logging level is INFO.

```
The logs are stored in the directory /tmp/<user.name>:

/tmp/<user.name>/hive.log
```

Note: In local mode, prior to Hive 0.13.0 the log file name was ".log" instead of "hive.log".